# UTM Parameters for Adwords Not Feeding correctly

Tags: google-analytics

I am having an issue where I am not seeing my specific UTM parameters feeding into analytics. Instead, Analytics is replacing the parameters with items from AdWords directly. This is causing an issue, as I am feeding ID's from adwords into the UTM Content field, and those ID's aren't propagating. Other than unlinking Adwords from Analytics, is there a way to receive the true field entries? I do believe that this is because we have the adwords and analytics accounts linked, but hoping for a work around.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED!

Sharing solution in case others run into a similar issue.

In order for UTM fields to override GCLID values. You go to Admin under Analytics settings > Property Settings > Advanced Settings > Check the box "Allow manual tagging (UTM values) to override auto-tagging (GCLID values) for Adwords and DoubleClick Search integration"

Hope this helps others!